# Reloading the page using href and invoking a function at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to create a link to a page as well as invoke a function at the same time .But the problem is i am unable to invoke a function either by using be onclick or onload.

onload the function is not invoked because the page is not reloaded

my code is as follows.

HTML Code

```
<body onload="loadData();">

<div  data-role="page" class="index"   >

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">

             <h1> EXPENSE SHEETS </h1>
             <a href="#expense_details"   data-role="button" data-transition="flip"   > +  </a> 

    </div><!-- /header --> 

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b"  > 
   <div id="contentexist"> If any stored expense data is there comes here  </div>


    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="false" data-filter="false" id="contenta">

    </ul><!-- /content --> 
</div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
       <a href="index.html"  class="headerButton" data-icon="home">home </a>
    <a href="index.html" class="headerButton" data-icon="back" > back</a>
    <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">menu</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-position-to="window" class="ui-content" >
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a
    <p>This is a completely basic menu, no options set.<p>
</div>     
    </div><!-- /footer --> 

</div> <!-- /page --> 

<div data-role="page" id="expense_details" class="index" >

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>  EXPENSE SHEET DETAILS  </h1>   

    <a href="#" class="headerButton" data-icon="check" id="savebtn" onclick="savebtn()"> Save</a>
    </div>

     <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">  
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" />
        </div>    

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" value="" />
        </div>

    </div>

      <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">

       <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="stotal">Sheet total</label>
            <input type="text" name="stotal" id="stotal" disabled="disabled"  />
        </div>
        <a href="index.html"  class="headerButton" data-icon="home">home </a>
         <a href="page1.html"  class="headerButton" data-icon="back">back</a>

       <a href="page1.html"  class="headerButton" data-transition="slidedown" > + </a> 




    </div>


</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function loadData(){



 $('#contenta').append( '<li> <a rel="external"   href=" '+b+'" > <br>'  + row.exp_title + '. ' + row.exp_date+ ' ' + a + '' + row.exp_comments + '</a></li>' );

    }
```

where  b ="page1.html#expense_details?" + row._id;

now i would like to invoke a function by using onclick but right now my onclick doesnt work and page too doesnt reload . is there anyway to reload the page .

Also i would like to add that the a tag  is dynamically created

append is nothing but just to say that the code is dynamic.

Comment: Please format your code better.

Comment: So when user clicks a link you neeed: a). a JS function to execute, b) after function executed - just reload current page - that's it? Or vice-versa?

Comment: Please explain sequence of events better...hard to follow

Comment: when user click a link i need the person to go to next page with the parameters and then the function to be invoked

Comment: not being clear explaining what happens on what page, and what the append in code is for. Please be concise...step 1, step2 etc

Comment: Where you want to invoke the function, in the page right you are or in the second page once you navigate away by click ?

Comment: @RCV : once i navigate to the next page

Comment: Is there some reason for you not to be using $document.ready() on the new page?

Comment: i tried invoking a function using document.ready but it doesnt seem to work ...

Comment: how can anyone help you when you haven't explained what this function should do and what it has to do with first page. Am voting to close this....people shouldn't have too ask this many questions to help you

Comment: So many answers could be posted but without checking your code those would be some dummy code and you can't make it working, so, post your code that you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring further information: you can't first refresh the browser's content by following and then executing a javascript function from the previous context (i.e. the page they were on when they clicked the link).

What you *can* do is fire a function when a user clicks on a link just before the browsers loads the link's new context. However, again, when the context is updated, the active page is pushed into the browser's history and has no effect whatsoever anymore.